# Django REST Framework caching bug

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, caching, django-rest-framework

## TL;DR

I am looking for a way to **clear the cache after a request, or completely disable it when running tests.** Django REST Framework seems to cache the results and I need a way around this.

## Long version and code

Well this turned out to behave very weird as I kept testing it. In the end, I got it to work, but I really don't like my workaround and in the name of knowledge, I have to find out why this happens and how to solve this problem properly.

So, I have an [APITestCase](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#test-cases) class declared like this:

```
class UserTests(APITestCase):
```

Inside this class, I have a test function for my `user-list` view, as I have a custom queryset depending on the permissions. To clear things up:

- a superuser can get the whole users list (4 instances returned),
- staff members cannot see superusers (3 instances returned),
- normal users can only get 1 result, their own user (1 instance returned)

#### The test function version that works:

```
def test_user_querysets(self):

    url = reverse('user-list')

    # Creating a user
    user = User(username='user', password=self.password)
    user.set_password(self.password)
    user.save()

    # Creating a second user
    user2 = User(username='user2', password=self.password)
    user2.set_password(self.password)
    user2.save()

    # Creating a staff user
    staff_user = User(username='staff_user', password=self.password, is_staff=True)
    staff_user.set_password(self.password)
    staff_user.save()

    # Creating a superuser
    superuser = User(username='superuser', password=self.password, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)
    superuser.set_password(self.password)
    superuser.save()



    # SUPERUSER

    self.client.logout()
    self.client.login(username=superuser.username, password=self.password)

    response = self.client.get(url)

    # HTTP_200_OK
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # All users contained in list
    self.assertEqual(response.data['extras']['total_results'], 4)



    # STAFF USER

    self.client.logout()
    self.client.login(username=staff_user.username, password=self.password)

    response = self.client.get(url)

    # HTTP_200_OK
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # Superuser cannot be contained in list
    self.assertEqual(response.data['extras']['total_results'], 3)



    # REGULAR USER

    self.client.logout()
    self.client.login(username=user2.username, password=self.password)

    response = self.client.get(url)

    # HTTP_200_OK
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # Only 1 user can be returned
    self.assertEqual(response.data['extras']['total_results'], 1)

    # User returned is current user
    self.assertEqual(response.data['users'][0]['username'], user2.username)
```

As you see, I am testing user permissions in this order: superuser, staff, normal user. And this works, so...

### Funny thing:

If I change the order of the tests, and start with normal user, staff, superuser, the tests fail. The response from the first request gets cached, and then I get the same response when I log in as staff user, so the number of results is again 1.

#### The version that doesn't work:

*it's exactly the same as before, only the tests are made in reverse order*

```
def test_user_querysets(self):

    url = reverse('user-list')

    # Creating a user
    user = User(username='user', password=self.password)
    user.set_password(self.password)
    user.save()

    # Creating a second user
    user2 = User(username='user2', password=self.password)
    user2.set_password(self.password)
    user2.save()

    # Creating a staff user
    staff_user = User(username='staff_user', password=self.password, is_staff=True)
    staff_user.set_password(self.password)
    staff_user.save()

    # Creating a superuser
    superuser = User(username='superuser', password=self.password, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)
    superuser.set_password(self.password)
    superuser.save()



    # REGULAR USER

    self.client.logout()
    self.client.login(username=user2.username, password=self.password)

    response = self.client.get(url)

    # HTTP_200_OK
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # Only 1 user can be returned
    self.assertEqual(response.data['extras']['total_results'], 1)

    # User returned is current user
    self.assertEqual(response.data['users'][0]['username'], user2.username)



    # STAFF USER

    self.client.logout()
    self.client.login(username=staff_user.username, password=self.password)

    response = self.client.get(url)

    # HTTP_200_OK
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # Superuser cannot be contained in list
    self.assertEqual(response.data['extras']['total_results'], 3)



    # SUPERUSER

    self.client.logout()
    self.client.login(username=superuser.username, password=self.password)

    response = self.client.get(url)

    # HTTP_200_OK
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # All users contained in list
    self.assertEqual(response.data['extras']['total_results'], 4)
```

I am working in python 2.7 with the following package versions:

```
Django==1.8.6
djangorestframework==3.3.1
Markdown==2.6.4
MySQL-python==1.2.5
wheel==0.24.0
```

## UPDATE

**I am using the default django cache, meaning I haven't put anything about cache in the django settings.**

As suggested, I tried disabling the default Django cache:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

**The problem stands on.**

Even though I don't think the problem is located here, this is my UserViewSet:

***api.py*** (the important part)

```
class UserViewSet(  
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, 
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserExpenseSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    allowed_methods = ('GET', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD')

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return UserExpenseSerializer
        return UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if(self.action == 'list'):
            return User.objects.all()
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return User.objects.all()
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return User.objects.exclude(is_superuser=True)
        return User.objects.filter(pk = self.request.user.id)

    def list(self, request):
        filter_obj = UsersFilter(self.request)
        users = filter_obj.do_query()
        extras = filter_obj.get_extras()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, context={'request' : request}, many=True)
        return Response({'users' : serializer.data, 'extras' : extras}, views.status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

***filters.py***

```
class UsersFilter:
    offset = 0
    limit = 50
    count = 0
    total_pages = 0
    filter_params = {}

    def __init__(self, request):

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.filter_params['is_superuser'] = False

        if (not request.user.is_superuser and not request.user.is_staff):
            self.filter_params['pk'] = request.user.id

        # Read query params
        rpp = request.query_params.get('rpp') or 50
        page = request.query_params.get('page') or 1
        search_string = request.query_params.get('search')

        # Validate

        self.rpp = int(rpp) or 50
        self.page = int(page) or 1

        # Set filter
        set_if_not_none(self.filter_params, 'username__contains', search_string)

        # Count total results

        self.count = User.objects.filter(**self.filter_params).count()
        self.total_pages = int(self.count / self.rpp) + 1

        # Set limits
        self.offset = (self.page - 1) * self.rpp
        self.limit = self.page * self.rpp

    def get_filter_params(self):
        return self.filter_params

    def get_offset(self):
        return self.offset

    def get_limit(self):
        return self.limit

    def do_query(self):
        users = User.objects.filter(**self.filter_params)[self.offset:self.limit]
        return users

    def get_query_info(self):
        query_info = {
            'total_results' : self.count,
            'results_per_page' : self.rpp,
            'current_page' : self.page,
            'total_pages' : self.total_pages
        }
        return query_info
```

## UPDATE 2

As Linovia pointed out, the problem was not cache or any other DRF problem, but the filter. Here's the fixed filter class:

```
class UsersFilter:

    def __init__(self, request):

        self.filter_params = {}
        self.offset = 0
        self.limit = 50
        self.count = 0
        self.total_pages = 0
        self.extras = {}

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
        # and so long...
```

Comment: If `self.client` is a `django.test.Client` and you're interacting as a different user, why not create a new `Client()`?  This should more closely  match the model of what is happening anyways.  A `Client` instance is a stand alone browser interaction with your site.  Perhaps that is why Django is getting confused.

Comment: I actually did try that, the same problem appears. It has something to do with the DRF caching. Another funny thing is that if I test the staff user before the normal user, the test passes. Blows my mind.

Comment: Are you sure you're limiting your results from the `url` you're querying?  What does your `queryset` parameter or `get_queryset()` function look like on that view?

Comment: Completely sure, checked it like 50 times in the browsable api :). I'll paste the queryset now.

Comment: As a matter of fact I can't do that, it also includes a filter function for the data that customizes the queryset with several query_params. However, this part works as I have tested it a lot of times and the application actually works as I want it to. And also, as I said, the test works if I make a request for a staff_user first :)))

Comment: Well shoot, man.  Time to go spelunking with [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) GUI debugger. Set a breakpoint in the view with the line `import rpdb2; rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger('foo')`.  Launch your test and watch it hang.  Then attach winpdb to django with `File`->`Attach`, et c.

Comment: I updated my question with a but explanation of the problem, it's a really funny behavior, so if you are interested in reading, be my guest :). Thanks for the recommendation, I will try it out.

Comment: One more thing. Perhaps it is a caching bug and it has been fixed.  Have you tried updating your version?

Comment: Django==1.8.6, djangorestframework==3.3.1, Markdown==2.6.4, MySQL-python==1.2.5, wheel==0.24.0. Everything is up to date I think. I am working with Python 2.7

Comment: You haven't posted anything that does any caching. You need to at least post the code from the view that is returning this data.

Comment: I haven't configured anything about caching, it's all default as django and the rest framework come. It is definitely the caching and the main question is how to disable it when running tests.

Comment: can you post your view function also? I need to see how are you using the queryset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you create a new user which should make 2 users and you assert the length against 3. Not going to work even without caching.

Edit:
So you actually have you issue because the use of mutables objects at the class level.

Here's the evil code:

```
class UsersFilter:
    filter_params = {}

    def __init__(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.filter_params['is_superuser'] = False
```

Which should actually be:

```
class UsersFilter:
    def __init__(self, request):
        filter_params = {}
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.filter_params['is_superuser'] = False
```

Otherwise UsersFilter.filter_params will be kept from one request to another and never resets. See http://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide for more details about this.

Comment: That is not the problem, I didn't put the entire code... There are 2 normal users created before this, and this code snippet starts after that. The problem is not some minor error, I know it is the caching after 2 hours of testing and trying different methods. I will update the snippet right away.

Comment: Question updated, you can take a look now if you want to.

Comment: Strange behavior. This feels like you've set the query set on the module or class level and filter after that which would work for first example because it'll have all the users and not in the second (only one item for the QS).

Comment: I updated the question with more information on that.

Comment: The relevant part is when and how you call the cache in the view or elsewhere. You should try to set the cache to dummy and see if that fixes or not. If not, it's unlikely Django or DRF fault. If it's still there it'll require further investigation.

Comment: That's the thing, I do not call the cache and i do not set it up. It's the default setting as Django and DRF come.

Comment: Updated, I tried disabling the Django cache, same problem :)

Comment: Ok, so as I said in my comment, it's because you're setting something at the class level. Updating my answer with the details.

Comment: It was working because you went from the widest filter to the smallest one. Therefore every new query was "hiding" the previous one

Comment: Ah, yes, I feel so dumb now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable caching in debug mode by adding this to your settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
    }
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#dummy-caching-for-development

You can then disable caching by toggling `DEBUG` in `settings.py` or by having separate develop/test and /deploy `settings.py` files.

---

If you want to avoid separate files or toggling, then you can set `DEBUG` to true for certain tests with the `override_settings` decorator:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings

class MyTest(TestCase):
    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_debug(self):
        self.assertTrue(settings.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's in the docs, but how can I disable it only when I'm running tests without editing the settings.py file every time?

Comment: You could add `if 'test' in sys.argv:` so this will only be defined when running `python manage.py test`.

In the past I've also used `if DEBUG:`.

Comment: `if DEBUG` sounds like a good solution, can you please provide a more elaborate answer with exact code sample, how to change cache engine inside code execution, so I can test and accept it?

Comment: Upvote for this info, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem (I even omitted the if clause, just disabled cache). I guess this doesn't have anything to do with Django, but some bug in DRF. I'm reading the docs over and over, and there is nothing on disabling cache, only those throttling classes that seem disabled by default. So weird...